# "nibble" vs. "nibble on"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I've been told by a native speaker that the verb "to nibble" can be used both with and without a preposition. So, is there a difference between

> I would definitely like to nibble on one of those sweet, sweet rodents!

and

> I would definitely like to nibble one of those sweet, sweet rodents!

<sup>See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/where-can-i-eat-a-guinea-pig-in-ecuador) on Travel-SE for some context.</sup>

Which one (or maybe both) are correct? Is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s little difference, as these two citations from the OED, both from the 1980s, show:

> She and Roy would nibble on each other.
>
> Encircling her slim waist with a fond arm, the husband of a fortnight
>   nibbles her throat.

Neither describes an act of cannibalism.

Comment: +1 for the clarification at the end of the succinct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without the preposition is more common, but with the preposition is gaining in popularity.[image: A graph showing the frequency of *nibble a* vs *nibble on a* in the Google books corpus]

Answer (score 0):

To "Nibble" is to bite chips off something, generally with the intention to eat it. "Nibble on" can have a connotation of playfulness, that may or may not include the actual eating.

Comment: Does this answer the question?  Any sources?